# PHP files that are called asynchronously via XmlHttpRequest

Tags: php, certificate

During my mock Zend PHP certification exams I have came across the following question that I have researched online but have not found a definitive, and understandable, answer to it. Can You advise what the answers to these may be or point me in the right direction?

Consider 3 PHP files that are called asynchronously via XmlHttpRequest:

// s1.php
 `session_start();`
 `sleep(1);`

// s2.php
 `session_start();`
 `sleep(2);`

// s3.php
 `session_start();`
 `sleep(3);`

---

Which of the following statements is true? (Choose two.)

A. The total execution time for all 3 requests will be the maximum of the longest sleep() call
B. The requests may be processed out of order
C. The requests are guaranteed to be executed in order
D. Concurrent requests will be blocked until the session lock is released

Comment: A+B, reasoning: **A**, since the calls are asynchronous and the slowest will take 3 seconds. In a perfect world (ignoring latency and stuff), if you start all calls right after another: `s1.php` would answer after ~1s, another second later `s2.php` response will come (total 2s from start), another second later `s3.php` response would come (total of 3s from the start). **B**, since they're 3 separate requests, they're not even guaranteed to take the same route to the server and the answer isn't guaranteed **to** take the same route **from** the server.

Comment: This is logical. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think is B and D.

[From PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#117157):

> PHP's session handler is blocking. When one of
> your scripts calls `session_start()`, any other script that also calls
> `session_start()` with the same session ID will sleep until the first
> script closes the session.
>
> A common workaround to this is call `session_start()` and
> `session_write_close()` each time you want to update the session.

[And](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#114209):

> If you need to keep a PHP page running after
> opening a SESSION, simply close it when finished writing to
> `$_SESSION` so the AJAX polling page can authenticate and use the same
> session in a seperate web page...
>
> `session_write_close();`

[And](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#101452):

> PHP locks the session file until it is closed. If you have 2 scripts
> using the same session (i.e. from the same user) then the 2nd script
> will not finish its call to `session_start()` until the first script
> finishes execution.
>
> If you have scripts that run for more than a second and users may be
> making more than 1 request at a time then it is worth calling
> `session_write_close()` as soon as you've finished writing session data.